# How to set maxcontentlength property in appsetting.json in .net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

need to set maximum request length in appsetting file.
In web.config we use,

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

For specifying the maximum request length, you could add `web.config` to your project and modify it like

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

You could check this from [[Discussion]: New default 30 MB (~28.6 MiB) max request body size limit](https://github.com/aspnet/ServerTests/issues/92).

You also could try [New default 30 MB (~28.6 MiB) max request body size limit #267](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267)

Comment: It looks like this question is specifically asking how to do this using appsettings.json rather than web.config